# Passing parameters to param tag dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, param

I want to pass the value to the  tag of applet dynamically.
I am taking the ID from session in this way and want to assign ID value to applet

```
var ID = Session[1];
```

Is this correct value of passing ID value to the applet dynamically
or is there any other better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fine to me:

```
<applet ...
    <param name="someParamName" value="@Session["someKey"]" />
</applet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback